# Is there any way to debug phantomjs in browser or set proxies outside selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have the issue that I need to use private proxies with `user:pass` authorization. If you look around as I did on doing this in selenium it seems almost impossible.

I was easily able to set proxies in phantomjs and then selenium uses them. I need to debug my phantomjs projects though and need the proxies active while debugging. So currently I can not have it both ways. Either debug with a browser but no proxies or use proxies headless and no browser. Saving screenshots simply isn't good enough because the errors often come from some positional error of the element which is only clear when I'm viewing browser activity.

So is there any other way that I could similarly set the proxies outside of selenium for their use. Or alternatively somehow actively view a browser when phantomjs is running, while I'm debugging?